# 401.2 Access Denied issue

Tags: web-applications, iis-7

I've been having some issues with the 401 2 unauthorized access issue.

Although the systems I manage typically run smooth sometimes the 401.2 error will popup on a website or web application configured in IIS.

All our systems are configured to run with Windows Authentication enabled and everything else is disabled.

Typically to resolve this issue for a web application I can remove the application and then re-add it without making any additional changes.

When the issue affects a website removing and re-adding it doesn't work. In addition to that I'd like to the root of what causes the random issues with this that popup.

I've compared copies of the web.config for the website and application.config with from various environments we have and found no setting that appears to be causing the issue.  I've even uninstalled and re-installed the windows authentication feature with no luck.

Please if you can give me some items to review and identify the issue I would appreciate it.

Comment: Additionally changing application pools has no effect on the authentication issue.  Most the pools use network service. And the Authentication Rules are setup to allow the appropriate individuals

Comment: A little more insight.  I've copied the web directory and created a new website using the same application pool.  The new website works as expected.  And checking the application.config before and after the website is setup, shows the only change was adding the website.

Comment: I resolved this issue by changing the physical path of the site to something else, then back to the correct directory.

I'd still like to find out the issue here, so if anybody can provide insight that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by changing the physical path of the site to something else, then back to the correct directory.

I'd still like to find out the issue here, so if anybody can provide insight that would be great.